# Spring XML tags exhaustive list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, documentation

I am working on writing some transformations for Spring and need the list of all the tags (just MVC for now), their properties and their hierarchy. I went through the documentation available on springsource.org but found them to be more suitable as a tutorial. Is there a place where I can find an exhaustive list of Spring MVC tags

Comment: What sort of tags?  JSP tags, or XML config tags?

Comment: It was such a complication to find the doc that i upvoted. Are we alone with Spring documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the XML Schema Definitions (.xsd's) at http://www.springframework.org/schema/.